# How to create Navigation Controller to connect Main View Controller to 2 Custom View Controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I need some help on how to create a Navigation Controller that loads its Root View Controller to a Main View Controller. Then, I want to have that Navigation Controller two selector buttons (leftBarButtonItem and rightBarButtonItem) that will take the user to 2 custom View Controllers (AboutViewController and SettingsViewController).

I was able to do this successfully but instead, I created the 2 view controllers inside the MainWindow.xib with all codes inside AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m. This is obviously not a good practice especially when you have a lot of custom view controllers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that it isn't good practice to create your view controllers in the AppDelegate.  Instead, you should create a separate ViewController for each view.  In the implementation file for your rootViewController, create methods to push the separate view controllers that you want to show when the buttons are pressed.  Something like this would work:

```
- (void)showAboutView
{
    AboutViewController *aboutViewController = [[AboutViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aboutViewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)showSettingsView
{
    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:settingsViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Then, include those methods in the selector field for your buttons. Like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *aboutBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(showAboutView)];

[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:aboutBarButtonItem];
```

This should take care of pushing your view.  The navigationController will automatically show a button to 'go back'.

In the AppDelegate, you would create the navigationController and tell it what view will be the rootViewController, like this:

```
ViewController1 *vc1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
mainNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi. I tried what you suggested and ended up with some errors. Can you please see my project here > http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7539490/WinNav%202.zip and help me solve those errors? Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: 1 - The code for creating the navigationController and rootViewController (currently way at the bottom of the AppDelegate, not in any method) should be included in the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Comment: 2 - You need to import both the AboutViewController.h and SettingsViewController.h files in the RootViewController.  Also import the RootViewController.h file in the AppDelegate.  3 - The code to push the Settings and About views is good, but you have only included code for one button in your navigation bar.  You will need another button to push the other view.  You can base that off the code for the first button, it should be exactly the same, other than changing names, actions and putting it on the Left side.  Also, you can change the button type, I included Action button just for reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments! I really appreciate it a lot! :D Will edit my code again and hope everything works out now. :)